# Getting rid of that damn image border in Firefox, not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, I've tried all 3 solutions, still not working, wondering if it is over written somewhere else, using Bootstrap 3.0. Seems so simple, yet driving me a bit bonkers.

1. `:focus { -moz-outline-style: none; }`
2. `* { outline: none; }`

3.

```
img {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
```

None of these solutions seem to be working.[image]

Comment: Give me url of that site/

Comment: have you tried throwing on `!important` to your code? Without more information, it is hard to determine what you are editing, and whether or not the code mentioned is being edited within bootstrap or if it is an override.

Comment: Here's a bare-bones version, with the border on click: http://preceptress.com

Comment: If you don't add other `:focus` styling, your page won't be accessible: http://outlinenone.com

Comment: Cool, yes, i stripped out all 3 of those choices, it was Bootstrap all along.  Thanks for that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in file `bootstrap.min.cs`s comment

```
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. Bootstrap.